# Use MongoDB Java Driver CommandListener directly from Core?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-java, vert.x, mongo-java-driver

I'm using Vert.x MongoDB Client which is built on the MongoDB Java Client Core lib. I'd like to use a CommandListener (which is part of Core) however it's not clear if

1. it's possible to use the CommandListener directly from Core, and
2. how to register the listener if it is possible

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't believe the MongoDB client exposes the core API. Would you mind to file an issue with your use case on https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-mongo-client ?

Comment: @tsegismont What I ended-up doing was weaving an aspect on `com.mongodb.async.client.MongoClientSettings.Builder.build()` This got my Listener in the mix. Would you still like an issue filed?

Comment: I guess it would be interesting to discuss the issue with the module maintainers